# BDBA (Black Duck Binary Analysis) triage scope misleading

Tags: security, vulnerabilities

In Black Duck Binary Analysis (a.k.a. Protecode) tool there are several options for vulnerability triaging

From Help:

> Triage scope
>
> You can apply a scope to a triaged vulnerability within a
>   third-party component. When triaging known vulnerabilities, you can
>   select from among the following options:
>
> **Account**: Applies to all uses of the component within the company
>   account
>
> **Group**: Applies to all uses of the component within the group
>
> **Application**: Applies to uses of the component within the same
>   application only
>
> **Application name**: Applies to uses of the component
>   within scanned applications having the same application name
>
> **File hash**: Applies to uses of the component within scanned applications
>   having the same file hash

What I want is to triage CVE in my library so the results of triage are carried over to the next scans. I'm expecting that "File hash" option should do exactly this, however, when I upload my archive next time, I still see the same CVE as non-triaged. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR - use "Group" scope.

**Details**

API documentation makes it a bit more clear

```
PUT /api/triage/vulnerability/

component - Component name
version - Component version
vulns - List of vulnerability ids
scope - Scope in which the triage affects. Possible values:

- CA - Account wide
- FN - Filename
- FH - File hash
- R - Result
- G - Group

product_id - In FN, FH and R scopes the related product

group_id - In G scope the related group
```

So actually triaging in the tool is done *not against the files*, but **against library versions** (library === component in the context). There is even no theoretical possibility to triage a file, because you triage the versions. Having this in mind, the rest of the thoughts are simple.

**What is the "File hash" then?**

It's clearly written that if you use "FH" the product_id will be required, and product is synonym (in current context) to uploaded archive with your binaries. So every product has one and only one "file hash" - hash of uploaded archive. Which makes this option completely useless, because, I assume, one is not uploaded 100 files separately, but uploads the archive\zip\tar.gz with the software, containing multiple binaries. And obviously, hash of the archive will change with every repackaging, even if there was a change in readme file.

> What I want is to triage CVE in my library so the results of triage are carried over to the next scans.

Since "file hash" is not suitable for this purpose, let's go thru other available scope options to see, what we can do here:

**Result**

The simplest and default option. In the same time, most useless. Maps directly to `Application` scope mentioned in Help: `Applies to uses of the component within the same application only`. In short - no any carry-over.

**Filename**

I personally find "filename" more clear than corresponding `Application name` line in Help. Regardless, this is also pretty clear - triaging will be carried over only if the name of the archive is the same. When it somehow solves the problem, it introduces the new issue - problem of differentiating different builds. Usually we name our zips like `MyCoolBuild_942_ab4e3f` so it's easy to find and check results for past builds. If you don't care, then this scope can be an option, if you name your zips as `MyCoolBuild.zip`.

**Group**

As one can guess, this is just group-wide triaging. If your team has its own group, then you're perfectly save to use it.

In my case, we have the whole company uploading files to one group, so we *may* have some conflicts, however, the manual for the tool says, that you should use version suffixes if you're making custom builds of this library (in order to fix some CVEs by yourself, for example). If everyone follows this rule, thus naming custom libraries not `1.0.2` but `1.0.2_company_build` then there will be no conflicts between triages from different teams.

**Account**

I don't know because I don't have this option in our BDBA instance -_-

**Testing correctness of assumptions above**

Everything from above can be easily confirmed by making couple of test uploads.

**File hash** - upload the same file twice under different names and triage a CVE with "FH" scope - then triage will be carried over.

**Filename** - upload archive once, then modify archive a little (add empty text file inside) and upload it again. Triage will be carried over.

**Group** - upload one library with auto-detected version, then modify the binary and upload it under different name - Triage will be carried over.

As an additional test, you can also upload archive with two libraries inside and override version for one of them - it will separate them in the UI and enable separated triaging.